# SASS output filename when 'watching' folder

Tags: css, sass

Morning,

I have installed SASS and Ruby and have been using it with much pleasure and delight. When I am watching a simgle file, I can specify the output file name to include .min like this:

`sass --watch css/scss/styles.css:css/styles.min.css --style=compressed`

This works fine.

However, how would I do the same when watching a folder with the following command:
`sass --watch css/scss:css --style=compressed`

This works fine for me for all files in the folder. But, it outputs the files as

> filename.css

I need to have the output file names to be

> filename.min.css

I have read various posts on https://github.com/subash/Prepros/issues/38, which seem to suggest editing a file called config.rb

I found two such files on my system, none of which are located in Ruby. I made the suggested changes, but to no avail.

How can I do this easily?

I have Ruby193 installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rename your files in to [filename].mini.sass so the output will be [filename].mini.css you can include the original files in "proxy" files with names like [filename].mini.sass and compile them.

You can create the configuration file [with compass](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/command-line/):
`compass config [path/to/config] [--sass-dir=sass --css-dir=css ...]`

[Here's a list of the configurations](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/configuration-reference/)